Determine equivalences in the generated collection of subgroups and quotients
Let $A$ be an abelian group, and $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_m$ be subgroups of $A$. Define the family of subgroups $\mathcal{D}_0 = \{ \{0\}, A, B_1, B_2, \dots, B_m \}$.
Let $\mathcal{C}_1$ be the collection of all finite intersections of elements in $\mathcal{D}_0$, i.e.
$$ \mathcal{C}_1 := \left\{ \bigcap S \mid S \subseteq \mathcal{D}_0 \right\}. $$
Let $\mathcal{D}_1$ be the collection of all finite sums of elements in $\mathcal{C}_1$, i.e.
$$ \mathcal{D}_1 := \left\{ \sum S \mid S \subseteq \mathcal{C}_1 \right\}. $$
We can define $\mathcal{C}_2, \mathcal{D}_2, \mathcal{C}_3, \mathcal{D}_3, \dots$ iteratively. Clearly, we have:
$$ \mathcal{D}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{C}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{D}_1 \subseteq \dots $$
Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the union of all these families, which we temporarily call the family of subsets generated by $(B_k)$.
In particular, elements of $\mathcal{D}_1$ are of the form $B_{i_1} \cap \dots \cap B_{i_r} + \dots$. Initially, I thought $\mathcal{C}_2 = \mathcal{D}_1$, so that $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{D}_1$, but a counterexample can be constructed when $m = 3$:
Let $A = \mathbb{R}^3$, $B_1$ be the $x$-axis, $B_2$ be the $y$-axis, and $B_3$ be the plane $x = y$. Clearly,
$$B_3 \cap (B_1 + B_2) = \{x = y, z = 0\} \in \mathcal{C}_2,$$
but this subset is not in $\mathcal{D}_1$.
This naturally leads to the following questions:

For finite $m$, does the defined increasing sequence of subgroups stabilize in finitely many steps? That is, does there exist an $N$ such that $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{D}_N$?

Given two elements $C_1, C_2 \in \mathcal{C}$, which are expressions involving finite intersections and finite sums of the form $\bigcap S$ and $\sum S$, is there an algorithm to determine whether these two subgroups are necessarily equal or contain one another? By "necessarily", I mean that for any choice of $A$ and $(B_k)$, the corresponding subgroups generated by the expressions must either be equal or one must contain the other. Thus, instead of thinking of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ as specific subgroups, it might be better to think of them as abstract expressions themselves. In particular, I would like to know if such an algorithm can express the subgroups in a "normal form", so that it is easy to determine whether there is a necessary equality or containment relation.


Given $C, D \in \mathcal{C}$, assuming $D \subseteq C$ (otherwise we can always replace $D$ with $C \cap D$), we may consider the quotient group $C/D$. The set of such quotient groups is denoted by $\mathcal{Q}$. Given two elements $C_1/D_1, C_2/D_2 \in \mathcal{Q}$, if $C_1 \subseteq D_1$ and $C_2 \subseteq D_2$, we can construct a map $\tau: C_1/D_1 \to C_2/D_2$ using inclusion maps and natural projections.
It is worth noting that sometimes this homomorphism $\tau$ must be an isomorphism, and by "must" I mean it in the same sense as "necessarily" before. A simple example of this is the Second Isomorphism Theorem: $A/(A \cap B) \cong (A + B) / B$.
In particular, we might wonder whether, due to the transitivity of isomorphisms, when $C_1, C_2$ and $D_1, D_2$ do not satisfy the above containment relations, we cannot directly construct a homomorphism $\tau$, but there might still be an isomorphism between $C_1/D_1$ and $C_2/D_2$ "indirectly". This is the question I am most interested in.

Given two elements in $\mathcal{Q}$, is there an algorithm to determine whether there is an "indirect" isomorphism between the quotient groups (induced by inclusion maps and natural projections)? I think one possible algorithm would involve considering all the isomorphisms in $\mathcal{Q}$ that arise from the Second Isomorphism Theorem, and then checking whether the two quotient groups can be connected through these isomorphisms.

This leads to a further question: Is the Second Isomorphism Theorem enough to "generate" all isomorphisms in $\mathcal{Q}$?

Are there two quotient groups in $\mathcal{Q}$ that are necessarily isomorphic, but we cannot prove their isomorphism using only the Second Isomorphism Theorem? I believe a non-trivial theorem related to quotient group equivalence is Zassenhaus' Butterfly Lemma, but its proof can still be derived from the Second Isomorphism Theorem.

This question might seem too technical or too abstract to answer, and may deviate from mainstream research topics, but I believe many people new to abstract algebra have probably had similar questions, only lacking the language to express them clearly. I think someone should ask these questions.
In particular, I feel this problem may have close connections to mathematical logic, especially model theory, and researchers in these areas may be interested in it. I am not sure if there is a mature framework in mathematical logic to address this problem, but perhaps we could design an algorithm to compute the equivalence of two quotient group expressions.
The following parts are background information, explaining why I became interested in this problem. I believe many people might have had similar thoughts during their studies.
I have only studied homology theory in algebraic topology, basic group-ring-field theory, and some module theory, but I haven't really delved into homological algebra. One of the things that I find "difficult" about homological algebra is that I cannot "internalize" certain diagram chasing theorems (such as the Snake Lemma). I can follow the proof and verify its correctness, but I don't really understand "what is going on." If I had not been introduced to the theorem beforehand, I feel like I would never have thought of such a result.
In particular, I feel like I am unable to "grasp the big picture". There are a vast number of diagram chasing lemmas in homological algebra, but I don’t know if these theorems really "reveal everything". Are some of these theorems essentially the same? I don't want to fall into the situation where I encounter a new formulation, think I've learned something new, only to realize that it is just another version of something I have already encountered.
On the other hand, I also don’t want to overlook something subtle and intricate hidden in seemingly trivial places, which I can't see because I am like a blind person to it.
I know that as I continue learning homological algebra, proving diagram chasing lemma after lemma, I will become more skilled, and these doubts will gradually improve. But I fear that by the time I do, I will have simply "gotten used to" it, becoming a "diagram-chasing machine" without really understanding the underlying issues.
"Puzzling Through Exaxt Sequences": A False Hope?
Therefore, when I came across Ravi Vikil's notes "Puzzling Through Exact Sequences" (which I highly recommend to anyone interested), I was very encouraged. In the notes, the author uses set-theoretic notions such as intersection, union, and difference to represent subgroup intersection, sum, and quotient. He also uses set equivalence to show the isomorphism of corresponding subgroups or quotient groups.
Using pictures to show these set relationships made the inclusion relations very clear, and I especially enjoyed the visual representations of the Snake Lemma and long exact sequences. Furthermore, the notes also discuss spectral sequences.
I truly wish that these diagrams could be more than just "intuitive illustrations." I hope to rigorously formalize such methods and actually apply them in research. This led me to ask this question on MSE two years ago, although at that time I lacked the language and energy to express clearly what I was seeking. I believe the insight I gained from Ravi Vikil’s notes can be summarized as follows:
Given an commutative diagram involving abelian groups $A$, $B$, $C$, and homomorphisms $f$, $g$, $h$, etc., each homomorphism gives rise to two subgroups: $\ker f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$. For any group $A$, we can consider all subgroups generated by these subgroups. If $g$ is a map from $A$ to $B$, we can also consider the images of these subgroups in $B$. We then look at all such subgroups and quotient groups generated from them.
In the diagram chasing lemmas, the commutativity of maps, chain complexes, and exact sequences are essentially telling us something very specific: certain subgroups and quotient groups (such as $\ker f / \operatorname{cok} g $) must be trivial.
When we consider these additional conditions, something magical happens: certain homomorphisms between subgroups and quotient groups suddenly become isomorphisms, and they become invertible. This leads to new isomorphisms, which sometimes allow us to define new maps, such as boundary operators in long exact sequences. I think this explanation is enough to justify the validity of the diagrams in Ravi Vikil's notes.
However, on the other hand, I believe that Ravi Vikil's intuitive approach cannot be fully formalized, or rather, we cannot fully understand the relationships between subgroups just using this method.
(Failure to) Represent Groups Using Cube
Let’s start with a good example: Let $A$ be an abelian group, and let $B_1$, $B_2$ be two subgroups of $A$. We can consider all subgroups and quotient groups generated by these:
$$ \{ 0 \}, A, B_1, B_2, B_1 \cap B_2, B_1 + B_2,$$
$$ A/B_1, A/B_2, A/(B_1 + B_2), B_1/(B_1 \cap B_2), B_2/(B_1 \cap B_2). $$
We can represent these sets with a square grid, where the left half represents $B_1$, the bottom half represents $B_2$, and the entire square represents $A$. The intersection of subgroups corresponds to the intersection of the respective sets, the sum corresponds to the union, and the quotient corresponds to the set difference.
Clearly, the right half of the square represents $A/B_1$, the top half represents $A/B_2$, the bottom left corner represents $B_1 \cap B_2$, and the top right corner represents $A/(B_1 + B_2)$. The top left corner can be $B_1/(B_1 \cap B_2)$, or $(B_1 + B_2) / B_2$, but the Second Isomorphism Theorem tells us they are isomorphic. Similarly, the bottom right corner can be understood using the same reasoning. I believe this square diagram is a very useful representation.
For a long time, I thought that when considering three subsets of $A$, namely $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$, one could get a similar cube diagram. We could also use intersection, union, and difference to represent subgroup intersection, sum, and quotient. However, when I actually tried to pursue this idea, I found a counterexample (the example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at the start of the question). This was very disappointing, and it led me to ask this question.
Even though we cannot represent the inclusion relations of subgroups in the diagram chasing lemmas using an intuitive method, are there other algorithms that could help reveal these relationships? Even though such an approach might be computationally complex, I believe it is still worth investigating whether such a general method exists. Perhaps we could even design an automated diagram-chasing program.

Q1 is answered negatively at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311064/is-the-lattice-generated-by-finitely-many-subspaces-in-a-finite-dimensional-vect , or rather at https://mathoverflow.net/a/213299/ .
